# meta_query not working

Tags: query, meta-query

I have a custom dropdown field in my media uploader which saves to the posts meta. Now I'm trying to get all images with a specific value with a meta_query. The variable `$author` is exactly the value that is saved in the postmeta in MySQL.

```
$rd_args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'post_slider_author',
            'value' => $author
        )
    )
);

$rd_query = new WP_Query( $rd_args );

$mh_posts = $rd_query->posts;
```

As you can see in the screenshot there is a value assigned to the meta `post_slider_author` and '1139' is also the correct ID. Unfortunately the query stays empty.

[image]

Additional:
I tried to disable all plugins but it had no effect. Normal queries work just fine.

Comment: The code here looks correct which means it's likely not something shown here that is causing an issue. You'll have to narrow down your issue through debugging conventions to get to the root cause. You may want to try logging the SQL via `$rd_query->request`

Comment: Is `post_slider_author` saved to the post or to the attachment? Keep in mind that by default `WP_Query` only queries posts. You need to set `post_type` if you want another post type.

Comment: @JacobPeattie `post_slider_author` is saved to the attachement but I also changed post_type to `attachment` -> no effekt

Comment: Can you `var_dump( $author )` right before the `$rd_args` to make sure it's not blank?  That'd be my first guess, is that it's checking for something that isn't there.  So we need to make sure that whatever `$author` passes to the `$rd_args` is the correct thing in the correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change it to `get_posts()` instead of `new WP_Query` and it works just fine. No idea what's the problem with the query.